# Indention in C++ Builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, indentation, code-formatting

In [C++ Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder), how can I make sure that even correctly nested code like:

```
void func () {

...
..

)
```

C++ Builder correctly nested only doing so:

```
void func ()

{

...
...

}
```

This is very stressful, because I always have to correct by hand. So how can I make which indents code as well in the first instance?

Comment: Which version of C++Builder are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The code formatter in C++Builder 2010 should do this automatically for you. (It is invoked with CTRL-D) You’ll have to set the preferences to how you like your code to be formatted, but this is a real time saver new with this most recent release.

Comment: I mean, when i typing words, and i'm going to do a block {} if i don't put down the { in a new line, the indentation results incorrent because when i press enter the caret are after the }, so i must give a new line. When i'm coding too, this is so tedious

Answer (score 2):

Select the block, then press CTRL+SHIFT+I.  This is in Borland C++ 6.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this free tools:

http://www.cnpack.org/index.php?lang=en

using tabs to shift marked blocks to left or right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a copy of this to run, but the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Formatting_Source_Code) mentions "Indentation, Spaces, and Line breaks" as some of the options under the formatter tab of the "Tools > Options" dialog.

What you're looking for is probably under the "Line Breaks" section.